# Switching between on-prem and cloud server IPs without load balancing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, load-balancing

I own a something.com domain and want to switch between an old on-premises server to a new Google Cloud VM. I can do that by changing the A record under DNS settings. If the new server fails I need to be able to switch back to the old server.

The problem with using A records is that DNS doesn't propagate fast even if you use Cloudflare. Google Chrome in particular sticks to its DNS table like crazy and if it first learned that something.com resolves to X.X.X.X it will not let go of it.

I need to be able to direct all traffic going to the Google Cloud static IP back to the old server's IP. I'm looking to find a proxy/routing rule menu that I can use to apply - not a full blown load-balancing menu that will cost extra per month.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get rid of the old server and build a more robust solution on GCP. There are multiple ways to do this, but one obvious way is to use a Managed Instance Group (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups). MIGs can be configured to be autohealing (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/high-availability-autohealing) and autoscaling (if needed).

In this case you should be particularly looking at stateful MIGs I guess (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs).

Comment: You're missing the point. It's about the transition from the old server to the new and then back to old if the deployment fails. You can't use the GCP static IP to proxy traffic from the old server without going via the convoluted Apache proxy within a VM.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from adding a load balancer in front of everything in GCP, pointing your DNS to that and then messing around with VM's on the backend to your hearts content? Nothing you've described so far gives me the impression that there would be value in preserving the old server. Why would you want to do it?

Comment: You still haven't read the original question. The load balancer is an extra item on the bill, last time I used it they charged a lot for it. It's an overkill also.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to switch your DNS from an IP to another one dynamically

- Either you use a DNS failover service, not proposed on GCP today. Use a low TTL in your DNS definition, else your will wait a lot before the automatic switch.
- Or you implement it by yourselves with a proxy server that you have to manage.

Comment: thanks, I already tried lowering TTL in Cloudflare but it still took all day

Comment: I was hoping there was some menu in the Networking section of GCP where one could set up a proxy without the hassle of doing it via Apache in the VM itself.